# Is Bayesian approach the correct way to solve this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, optimization, bayesian-optimization

I have a dataset that has 4 variables and the target is a value between 1 to 5. this data is generated from an api that is black box and I don't know the formula that generates these values.

I have been asked to find the values for x1,x2,x3, and x4 in a such way that my target is around 1.8.

now I see this as an optimization problem. I am a newbie in Bayesian world but something tells me I can solve it with Bayesian approach. I am really trying to understand Bayesian role in solving this problem.

Am I wrong here? Should I build the model to estimate the formula and then optimize it?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're wanting to do. Are you trying to find a formula that would give an output of ~1.8 given the data you have for the 4 variables? Or something else?

Comment: Do you only have this fixed dataset of inputs/outputs, or can you query the API with new sets of `x`s?

Comment: Is the output of the black box random? And this sounds like a root-finding problem, rather than an optimization problem. You have a black box, which is some unknown function $f$ (or random variable, maybe?), and you want to solve the equation $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = 1.8$. Techniques for root-finding and optimization are often related, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: And I'm not sure a Bayesian approach is what you want here. If the unknown is a function $f$, then a Bayesian approach would involve putting a prior over the space of functions. Unless you know a parametric form of the possible functions $f$ that would let you convert this to a statement about the parameters of those functions, you should do something else.

Comment: The secant method might be your best option here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method

Comment: @Elenchus I don't care about the function really, I want to know given a fix output (say 1.8) what could be the possible value of my input vector.

Comment: @Dougal No it is a fixed dataset and I cannot use the API, but the data is quite large

Comment: @ericperkerson can't I use a Gaussian prior and use the data that I have to update?

Comment: @EmmaStin Is the output of your black box function random? If you have access to it and you input the same values of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ twice do you get the same output both times?

Answer (score 3):

The “typical” Bayesian way to do this (at least, it seems typical to someone with my background – I’m sure others would greatly disagree) would go like this:

- There is some unknown function $f(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is a four-element vector. You have (possibly noisy) observations of $f(\mathbf{x}_i) = y_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, N$. You want to find an $\mathbf x$ such that $f(\mathbf x) \approx 1.8$.
- We’re going to need to assume that $f$ is, in some sense, “smooth.” If we don’t assume anything, then we can’t do anything at all. But what kind of assumption we make is going to determine how our process goes.
- The most common general-purpose assumption is that $f$ follows a [Gaussian process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process), with some general-purpose covariance function like a squared exponential (Gaussian) or Matérn. You can choose a family of covariances, perhaps based on prior knowledge about what $f$ “should” look like, and then select parameters (of the covariance, maybe a mean function, and the amount of observation noise) to maximize the marginal likelihood of your observed dataset.
- Once you’ve selected a prior for $f$, you can find a posterior distribution for the $f$ after observing your dataset; there’s a simple formula to follow there.
- Then, you can find the $\mathbf x$ that, say, minimizes $\mathbb E (f(\mathbf x) - 1.8)^2$. This will probably take some numerical optimization, e.g. gradient descent.

There’s good software out there to help with this process; for instance, if I were doing this I’d expect the whole thing should be less than 30 lines of code in [GPflow](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow) or [GPyTorch](https://gpytorch.ai/), but if you’re not familiar with TensorFlow or PyTorch respectively then software packages in your preferred language of choice might be easier to use.

---

All of this assumes, of course, that (a) you have reasonably noisy data and/or (b) you don’t have any training points with outputs near 1.8. If the API is deterministic and you happened to get a dataset point with $y = 1.813$, well, use that $\mathbf x$ and call it a day.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation. what is the difference between this method and using regressions to calculate the f and then minimize the function with gradient descent?

Comment: This is exactly an instance of that, using gaussian process regression.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from the comments, you'll still need to have some sort of model. You could  have a prior for each variable and update them with your data, and that might tell you about the distributions that generated the variables, but it doesn't tell you anything about how they're linked together. Typically, a Bayesian approach would put priors over the parameters of a model, as @ericperkerson mentioned.

I would first try multiple linear regression, which can be done in either a frequentist or Bayesian way. It will fit an equation to explain the relationship between the input variables and the output variable, from which you can then estimate the values of the inputs when the output is 1.8. The advantage of the Bayesian approach is it allows for uncertainty in the parameters, as they are drawn from a distribution rather than being point estimates, but that may not be of interest to you if you are not interested in the function itself.

Comment: is it correct to say if we find the distribution of Y, we know the joint probability of x1,x2,x3, and x4? can I run mcmc to find the distribution of Y based on the samples from Xs and then filter out all the input vectors that would lead to y=1.8?

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. You need a connection between them. Sampling from the probabilities just means you have samples. How do you know whether the sample output is connected to the inputs or not?

Comment: Actually you might be looking for a continuous variable Bayesian network, but I'm not aware of packages in any typical data science language which cover those